# accordion collapse jquery

Tags: jquery, accordion

I am using the accordion plugin, and when a user click anywhere on the page that is not the accordion I want the accordion to collapse any open lists.

The code I have below works in the sense that it collapses the accordion, but it still collapses it wheni  click on it.

What I am lookin for (i think), is a selector that will select everything, and then remove things like #accordion, and any li's that are related to the accordion.

```
$('html').not('#accordion, li').click(function(){

        collapseAll();              
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

[Use jQuery to hide a DIV when the user clicks outside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-div-when-click-outside-it)

Just incase anyone stumbles across this question, i found my answer here ^^

Answer (score 0):

`html` selector is wrong here. You want all items but #according. And this will be

```
$('*').not('#accordion, li').click(function(){

        collapseAll();              
});
```